# What is this structure called in English grammar?

Tags: parsing, absolute-construction

> A rush of blood to the head, and X committed hara-kiri.

This is how a cricket commentator once described a batsman who stepped out of the crease and attempted to loft the ball into the stands; however, he lost his wicket.

> Is there any special name for constructions like *A rush of blood to the head*? Is it a nominative absolute or is there another name for such constructions in English grammar?

Comment: It's an *idiom*, meaning, as you may know, **in a moment of madness.**  [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/idiom) has this definition (among others): **idiom** *a group of words whose meaning cannot be predicted from the meanings of the constituent words, as for example (It was raining) cats and dogs*.

Comment: Or were you asking about the absence of the subject and verb: "He had a rush of blood..."? Well, subjectless sentences - "Had a quick coffee" - are known as 'diary drop'. But with neither subject nor verb, *headlinese* maybe. Or [Telegram style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram_style) perhaps.

Comment: Thank you, @Old Brixtonian. But I'm more interested in the parsing of the sentence.